# Is authentication/authorisation necessary between a web server and an isolated application server?

Tags: authentication, web-application, authorization

If I have a system that consists of

- an application server which responds to requests made only from the web server.
- a web server that responds to client requests over the internet.

Is it necessary if I want to keep my data 'safe' to implement some sort of authentication between the two?

Ideally I would have these two physical machines connected in such a way that the application server is not connected directly to the public internet, only to the web server and then IP restrict requests so the application server only responds to the web server.

In reality each will probably be hosted on a VPS, so what's connected to what else is a null issue.

Is IP restricting requests considered safe enough in this case or do I need something stronger? If so, will a simple username/password combination be safe enough?

Comment: Most VPS providers let you create a private network, which is a slightly stronger control than IP restrictions. It is very common to connect web and app servers using a private network, and no authentication.

Comment: would you lock your front door? - *of course*! would you lock your kitchens door? depends what's in there...

Comment: Consider this: What will happen to the application server if your web server is somehow compromised?

Comment: You can implement authentication minimal change to your application code by using TLS mutual authentication. Depending on your VPS provider, your data may travel through the provider's internal network unencrypted possibly between physical machines. Whether this is or isn't an issue depends on how much you trust your VPS provider and how you value your data.

Comment: I've sent a sales enquiry to a few providers. I know AWS lets you do this but I'd prefer to use DigitalOcean. If I'm going to implement **some** authentication to ensure the identity of the web server is what it says it is, is there an industry standard method I should go and research?

Comment: We do something similar to this and still require our isolated app servers to use a username/key authentication.  You could use an SSH tunnel with a shared RSA key or have your web server connect via TLS.  It really depends on how your app is structured.  It's definitely worth adding an extra layer of protection since your public web server is going to get constantly hammered by hackers.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox - If your web server is compromised, the attacker can access your application server, just as the legitimate web server can. Doesn't matter whether you use authentication or not - the hacker has already compromised the web server, so they can grab the credentials.

Comment: @LieRyan - if you don't trust your VPS provider, you're pretty much screwed. They can access your VM's memory and extract credentials, encryption keys, etc.

Comment: @DaniEll Thats the best answer to this question, really.